# How to fix it? By pressing “Print Summary”, there are 2 extra blank pages printed

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-views, debugging

By pressing "Print Summary", there are 2 extra blank pages printed. One of them is before the content and the other is after. How can I make them disappear? I'm using CiviCRM version 5.10.4. Thanks.[image]

Comment: At first I was going to blame it on your theme, but I have the same result. It throws an error related to jQuery. I think there may be a bug related to the print summary function.

Answer (score 1):

There is CSS that is adding the space. When I remove the height for the following it will not print blank pages.

crm-container div.form-item {
height: 100%;
}

I would create an "extras.css" so that you can override some of the built-in CSS. You can specify a custom CSS file under Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs: Custom CSS URL. 
*Note: the path to the CSS file should be accessible from a web browser.*

If you add the following to the extras.css then it will fix the print of extra pages:

```
#Print1 div.form-item {
    height: 0;
}
```

When you go to print summary you can cancel the chrome printing pop-up and then inspect the CiviCRM page (it has the "print" and "done" buttons). You can further refine the print style using the Chrome Dev tools.

Comment: Thanks very much, it works. However it changes other pages style.

Comment: Interesting. I thought the id #Print1 was unique to the print page, which should make it only impact print pages. You may need to target the CSS a little bit more if this is not the case with your theme. 

Trying using this instead: 
form#Print1>div.form-item { height: 0; }

Comment: From my experience not all printed pages within CiviCRM are affected by custom CSS. Case in point, if I choose to print a membership record, it imports /sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/print.css and does not make any reference to the custom stylesheet that is set in Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs.